# Ruby: Reading contents of a xls file and getting each cells information

Tags: ruby, spreadsheet, xls

[This](http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/ndsj/2012/html/C0201e.xls) is the link of a XLS file. I am trying to use Spreadsheet gem to extract the contents of the XLS file. In particular, I want to collect all the column headers like (Year, Gross National Product etc.). But, the issue is they are not in the same row. For example, Gross National Income comprised of three rows. I also want to know how many row cells are merged to make the cell 'Year'.

I have started writing the program and I am upto this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'spreadsheet'

rows = Array.new
url = 'http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/ndsj/2012/html/C0201e.xls'
doc = Spreadsheet.open (open(url))
sheet1 = doc.worksheet 0
sheet1.each do |row|
      if row.is_a? Spreadsheet::Formula
          # puts row.value
          rows << row.value
     else
          # puts row
          rows << row
     end
  # puts row.value
end
```

But, now I am stuck and really need some guideline to proceed. Any kind of help is well appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'spreadsheet'

rows = Array.new
temp_rows = Array.new
column_headers = Array.new
index = 0
url = 'http://www.stats.gov.cn/tjsj/ndsj/2012/html/C0201e.xls'
doc = Spreadsheet.open (open(url))
sheet1 = doc.worksheet 0
sheet1.each do |row|
   rows << row.to_a
end

rows.each_with_index do |row,ind|
  if row[0]=="Year"
    index = ind
    break
  end
end

(index..7).each do |i|
  # puts rows[i].inspect
  if rows[i][0] =~ /[0-9]/
    break 
  else
    temp_rows << rows[i]
  end 
end

col_size = temp_rows[0].size
# puts temp_rows.inspect

col_size.times do |c|
  temp_str = ""
  temp_rows.each do |row|
    temp_str +=' '+ row[c] unless row[c].nil?
  end
  # puts temp_str.inspect
  column_headers << temp_str unless temp_str.nil?
end
puts 'Column Headers of this xls file are : '
# puts column_headers.inspect
column_headers.each do |col|
  puts col.strip.inspect if col.length >1
end
```

Comment: I could get a way that serves my purpose for now.